# How to see if redis is installed from within a python shell

Tags: python

From the shell prompt I can easily view whether I have redis on my machine by doing:

```
PROD WEB ➜  /home  redis
~redis
```

How would I do the same from within the python shell? Do I have to use a `subprocess` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a module of redis, and use it. For example:

```
import redis
redis.Redis('localhost', .....)
```